# mySQL - multiple LEFT JOIN needs adjustment for special null occurence

Tags: mysql

**I'm trying to also SELECT report_id and report_name in the case where the sub_category_id is NULL**

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
table research_category

category_id | category name
---------------------------
1           | category_one
2           | category_two
3           | category_three


table research_sub_category

sub_category_id | category_id | sub_category name
-------------------------------------------------
1               | 1           | sub_category_one
2               | 3           | sub_category_two


table research_report_detail

category_id | sub_category_id | report_id | report_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1               | 1         | Awesome Report
2           | NULL            | 2         | Awesome? We'll Never Know, Report
3           | 2               | 3         | Another Boring Report, yo
```

**The query below returns the structure I want, but I can't seem to return the report_id | report_name of the case where the sub_category_id is NULL.**

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, s.sub_category_id, s.sub_category_name, r.report_id, r.report_name
FROM research_category AS c
LEFT JOIN research_sub_category AS s
ON c.category_id = s.category_id
LEFT JOIN research_report_detail AS r
ON s.sub_category_id = r.sub_category_id
LEFT JOIN research_report_detail AS r2
ON c.category_id = r2.category_id
AND r2.sub_category_id IS NULL
```

**RETURNED DATA:**

```
category_id|category_name |sub_category_id|sub_category_name|report_id|report_name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          |category_one  |1              |sub_category_one |1        |Awesome report
2          |category_two  |NULL           |NULL             |NULL     |NULL
3          |category_three|2              |sub_category_two |3        |Boring Report
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: Changed the following**

```
AND r2.sub_category_id = NULL
```

to

```
AND r2.sub_category_id IS NULL
```

But got the same result ...

**DOUBLE EDIT: Added another report to data to make question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should match with the updated question:
Instead of using two instances of research_report_detail, you should use just one,
with a join condition that joins it to research_sub_category if and only if
sub_category_id is given (not null).

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name,
       s.sub_category_id, s.sub_category_name,
       r.report_id, r.report_name
FROM research_category AS c
LEFT JOIN research_sub_category AS s
ON s.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN research_report_detail AS r
ON r.category_id = c.category_id
AND (r.sub_category_id = s.sub_category_id OR r.sub_category_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: This selects all of the reports I want, however, I also need the results that don't contain report records.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to show the sub_category => category association in my original question. See edited question ...

Comment: Are the subcategories uniquely identified by sub_category_id, or can the same sub_category_id occur in different categories?

Comment: I hereby nominate Terje D. for "Person of the Day - November, 27th, 2012 - Earth"   -   THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using "is null"  I think the issue is that you are trying to use the equal sign (=). Null is doesn't exist so you can't check if it is equal to a value.

Check out this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: Seemed promising but got the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

change

```
SELECT c.category_id, ... r.report_id, r.report_name
```

to

```
SELECT c.category_id, ... r2.report_id, r2.report_name
```

Comment: Seemed promising but got the same result :(

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to show the sub_category => category association in my original question. See edited question ...